# navigate without view jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I want to override onbackpressed(). onBackPressed() shoud navigate to home fragment. But for navigation I need view, which I don't have. How to do this?

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
    findNavController(*/here it shows error/*).navigate(R.id.action_global_postsHolderFragment)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate), there are `findNavController` methods that are suitable for a View, Fragment, or Activity.

Assuming your `NavHostFragment` has an `android:id="@+id/nav_host"` and that you have included the `-ktx` artifacts in your `build.gradle`, you could use:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    findNavController(R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.action_global_postsHolderFragment)
}
```